# Sequences and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $K$ be the set of all infinite sequences $(k_n)_n\geq1$ of $0's$ and $1's$ and give it the metric for which $d((k_n),(c_n))$ is equal to $0$ if the sequences
 are equal and $2^{-m}$ where $m$ is the least $n$ such that $k_n \neq c_n$ otherwise

Show that the function $K\to{\mathbb R}$ that takes $k_n$  to $\sum_n k_n2^{-n}$  is continuous.  What is its images?  When are two sequences mapped to the same number?

Comment: Such a question to this level...I bet you already know one thing or two and you can show us your efforts.

Comment: i tried to show continuity with $\epsilon - \delta$ but i fail to succeed

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $\langle k_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a sequence of $0$’s and $1$’s, then

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}k_n2^{-n}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{k_n}{2^n}\tag{1}$$

is the number whose binary representation is $0.k_1k_2k_3k_4\ldots_{\text{two}}$. For instance, if $k_1=1$ and $k_n=0$ for $n\ge 2$, $(1)$ is simply $0.1_{\text{two}}=\frac12$. If $k_1=0$ and $k_n=1$ for $n\ge 2$, $(1)$ is

$$\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{2^n}=\frac{\frac14}{1-\frac12}=\frac12=0.011111\ldots_{\text{two}}\;.$$

If $k_n=0$ for odd $n$ and $k_n=1$ for even $n$, then $(1)$ is

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{2^{2n}}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{4^n}=\frac{\frac14}{1-\frac14}=\frac13=0.01010101\ldots_{\text{two}}\;.$$